# Error while compiling in Zephir

Tags: c, gcc, zephir

I'm trying a simple "Hello World" in Zephir. I created the project with `zephir init utils`.

The json contains the `namespace`:

```
  "namespace":"utils",
  "name":"utils"
```

I followed these [steps](http://docs.zephir-lang.com/en/latest/tutorial.html)

---

```
PHP 5.3.27 (cli) (built: Nov 19 2013 08:41:19)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies

GNU Make 3.81

Zephir version 0.9.2a-dev

gcc-Version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) (GCC)
```

Error Message

> [root@local`host utils]# php -r 'echo PHP_BINARY, "\n";';
>   /usr/local/share/php-5.6.19/bin/php [root@localhost utils]# zephir
>   build PHP Warning: PHP Startup: zephir_parser: Unable to initialize
>   module Module compiled with module API=20090626 PHP compiled with
>   module API=20131226 These options need to match in Unknown on line 0
>   Fatal error: Call to undefined function Zephir\zephir_parse_file() in
>   /usr/local/share/zephir/Library/CompilerFile.php on line 173`

Comment: I don't see error message in your post, can you edit to add it ?

Comment: Sorry that I hav forgot he error messagt. First I set the PHPB Binary, an then I try to build:  `[root@localhost utils]# php -r 'echo PHP_BINARY, "\n";';
/usr/local/share/php-5.6.19/bin/php
[root@localhost utils]# zephir build
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: zephir_parser: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20131226
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
Fatal error: Call to undefined function Zephir\zephir_parse_file() in /usr/local/share/zephir/Library/CompilerFile.php on line 173`

Answer (score 0):

I believe your phpize is for PHP 5.3 but you try to use PHP 5.6 binary. Try to run `phpize -v` to view your PHP Api version.